# AWS t2.small instance some time goes down for small fraction of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, instances

I am using the aws t2.small instance under the ALB and have setup the data-dog alerts, if host goes down, which collects the data from AWS load balancer.

once in a 2 days, i get the alert the host count thresold is below 1.but it automatically recover within 10 minutes. below is the aws cloud-watch metric for load-balancer, there also it shows host was down for a small fraction of time.

[image]

I am not able to figure out why it happens and is there is any way by which we can debug that.

Comment: what kind of healthcheck do you have configured in the ALB?

Comment: datadog has ia integration with aws and i am using it for my healthcheck.

Comment: datadog has nothing to do with this, ALB runs healthchecks, they probably fail, check your application logs at that time

Comment: i just searched in my application logs and saw my service was restated during that time. its running as a docker service in aws ecs instance and found there one event which says service de-register with ELB.

Comment: let me know how can i find the detail of event in aws ecs console.

Comment: more interesting might be to find out why the service was restarted

Comment: there is no clue in log, why it was restarted, but in aws ecs events it shows insufficient memory on host.